# WAI application works ghci but not with runhaskell

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, haskell-wai

I have written a simple WAI application, which uses a ReaderT to allow access to the request like so:

```
import qualified Network.Wai as W
handle :: (Resource a) => a -> ReaderT W.Request IO W.Response
```

where `handle` is the function that does the bulk of the processing. I then call it in my application:

```
app :: W.Application
app = runReaderT (handle a) -- simplified; i don't think the value of a matters

main :: IO ()
main = run 3000 app
```

but `runhaskell main.hs` gives me the following:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.ResourceT
                                IO'
            with actual type `IO'
Expected type: ReaderT
                 W.Request (Control.Monad.Trans.Resource.ResourceT IO) W.Response
  Actual type: ServerMonad W.Response
In the return type of a call of `handle'
In the first argument of `runReaderT', namely
  `(handle a)'
```

which confuses me for two reasons:

1. I don't have any idea why it's expecting that type
2. Calling `resp <- runReaderT (handle a) defaultRequest` works in GHCI!

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `Application` is defined as:

```
type Application = Request -> ResourceT IO Response
```

(The reason for ResourceT is so that you can allocate scarce resources and use them when sending a streaming response. This would be relevant for sending back a response based on a large database query. But that's not directly relevant for your question.)

Your `runReaderT (reader a)` has type `Request -> IO Response`. In order to get it to return the response in `ResourceT IO`, there seem to be two options:

1. Lift it in `app`: `app = lift . runReaderT (reader a)`. (`lift` is defined in `Control.Monad.Trans.Class`.)
2. Change the type of `hanlde` to `handle :: (Resource a) => a -> ReaderT W.Request (ResourceT IO) W.Response`.

The first approach makes sense if you might ever need to perform a resource-sensitive operation, whereas the second will likely be an easier change.

Comment: I was looking at an old version of the Network.Wai docs -- d'oh! Thanks very much.